# Unfortunately App has stopped , with zero errors

Tags: java, android

None of these apps would work even though I'm 100% sure there are no errors.
When I launch the app it just tells me that it has stopped. Here is my code

This is the activity

```
TextPlay.java

package com.example.txt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class TextPlay extends Activity{

Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
ToggleButton passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);
}
```

And the layout

```
text.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="25dp"
tools:context=".TextPlay" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etCommands"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edittext1"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:text="@string/button1" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/tbPassword"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:checked="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/toggle1" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvResults"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/tv1" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

and the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.txt"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".TextPlay"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try moving init of Views inside onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);

    Button chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
    ToggleButton passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
    TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
}
```

**EDIT:**

if you need objects to be accessible class-scope, declare them out of the method
and init them in the method:

```
Button chkCmd;
ToggleButton passTog;
EditText input;
TextView display;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.text);

    chkCmd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bResults);
    passTog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbPassword);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etCommands);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResults);
}
```

Comment: It Worked . But if i added them to onCreate it wont be local , right ?

Comment: @MohamadNabeel i have updated the answer, in case you need them class-scope, you can declare them as member variables, and init them inside `onCreate()`